# What's the advantage of using express' session over the HTML5 global sessionStorage object?

Tags: node.js, session, cookies, express, session-storage

My understanding is that, in apps using express on top of node, the session object can be accessed through `req.session`, which can have any number of key/value pairs set on it.

What's the advantage of using this method over storing key/value pairs on the global sessionStorage object in the DOM?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several advantages:

- `express.session` stays on your server, so you can store things there that won't be accessible to the client
- express sessions don't have storage limits
- Storing things in the DOM mean you'll have to transmit everything over the wire, incurring extra bandwidth costs.